# How to use a ListView for keys (String) in a map, and have a drop down ListView for the keys value (List<String>)?

Tags: android

I've looked at BaseAdapter, and creating a sublist for each list item. I can't figure out how (or if I even should) make the BaseAdapter use the map keys and the list values associated with them.  It shouldn't be too difficult, but I'm new to Android.  Should I create a new ArrayAdapter for the value of each key in the map?  What's the best practice for making sublists in a list?

I'm making a recipe app and have the ingredients as keys in a map.  The user's shopping list will show all ingredients he or she needs to buy, with a drop down so when he or she is at the store, she can drop down the ingredient and see how much is needed for all her recipes with that ingredient that week.  I have my joins and pojos set up to handle things from a db using Room.  Async tasks are set up to add things to the map as needed.  Just need to figure out how to get this shopping list view set up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the best practice for making sublists in a list?

You can try to use `ExpandableListView` instead

link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView